# Delay the http retry request task in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, asynchronous, nsurlconnection, delay

I am retrying to send a HTTP async request in the event of a 4XX error. I am doing this in the NSURLConnection delegate methods:

```
      - (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
        {

         if(httpResponseStatusCode == 404) 
         { 
             [MyModel doGet:[connection currentRequest].URL delegate:self timeout:HTTP_TIMEOUT ]; 
         }    
        }
```

But this request is being triggered too early (before the server has a response for me). How should I add a delay such that the request is triggered after a delay of 2 sec?

I tried using performSelector with delay but I get a EXC_BAD_ACCESS when executed.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why do you think the server has not completed, you got the completion code 4xx.

Comment: The server is waiting for a message from a third party service, so as soon it receives it, it sends a valid response to the app's request

Comment: Are you using WebSockets?

Comment: I am using asynchronous nsurlconnection to trigger the request

Comment: Have you tried dispatch_after ?

Comment: @anhtu - Thank you for the dispatch_after. I tried and it worked well. Please post it so I can mark it as the answer. Here's the snippet -`dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(5.0 * NSEC_PER_SEC)), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                [MyModel doGet:[connection currentRequest].URL delegate:self timeout:HTTP_TIMEOUT ];
            });`

Comment: `dispatch_after` would work here but, for a 404 i don't think retrying the request will help your 404 not found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try dispatch_after to delay the request call. Here's the snippet

```
    dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(5.0 * NSEC_PER_SEC)), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{ 
        [MyModel doGet:[connection currentRequest].URL delegate:self timeout:HTTP_TIMEOUT ]; 
    });
```

Thanks you.